# build project into different repositories with different jdks

Tags: java, maven, repository

I am facing problem where I need to build same project into different local repositories where each repository is based on different JDK version (1.6 and 1.7). Is it possible to configure for example settings.xml and its profiles to be able build projects this way?

Modifying pom files is not a solution for me since there is quite large number of projects which should be prepared this way and I am not only one who works and updates pom files.

I found only solution for switching repositories via mvn call http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3588

Comment: Why are you building into repositories? Can't you just set up separate build jobs via for example Jenkins?

Comment: I do not use any auto build tool. I just need to prepare jar and war files in specific build version in specific repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses JAVA_HOME variable to find the java compiler to be used. So one solution will be to set the JAVA_HOME appropriately on different environments.

Comment: Thanks it is somehow described here http://unserializableone.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/compile-and-test-with-different-jdk.html.

Comment: There's another way: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-toolchains-plugin/toolchains/jdk.html

Comment: @RobertScholte The method mentioned on that link requires the pom file change, which user does not want to do.